# File upload fails when file is over 60K in size

Tags: linux, perl, http, unix, command-line-interface

I have been working to convert an in-house application away from using FTP, as the security team has told us to get off FTP. So I've been using HTTP uploads instead, and for the most part it works very well. Our environment is a mishmash of Linux, HP-UX, Solaris, and AIX. On our Linux servers, curl is universally available, so I have been using curl's POST capabilities for uploads, and it's worked flawlessly. Unfortunately, the Unix machines rarely have curl, or even wget, so I wrote a GET script with perl which works fine, and the POST script I wrote for perl(lifted and adapted from elsewhere on the web) works brilliantly for Unix, up until the data being uploaded is greater than about 60K(which curl handles fine in Linux, btw). Beyond that, the Apache error log starts spitting out:

```
CGI.pm: Server closed socket during multipart read (client aborted?).
```

No such error ever occurs when I use curl for the upload. Here's my POST script, using Socket, since LWP is not available on every server, and not at all on any of the Unix servers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Socket;

my $v        = 'dcsm';
my $upfile   = $ARGV[0] or die 'Upload File not found or not specified.' . "\n";
my $hostname = $ARGV[1] or die 'Hostname not specified.' . "\n";
$| = 1;

my $host  = "url.mycompany dot com";
my $url   = "/csmtar.cgi";
my $start = times;
my ( $iaddr, $paddr, $proto );
$iaddr = inet_aton($host);
$paddr = sockaddr_in( 80, $iaddr );
$proto = getprotobyname('tcp');

unless ( socket( SOCK, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto ) ) {
    die "ERROR : init socket: $!";
}
unless ( connect( SOCK, $paddr ) ) {
    die "no connect: $!\n";
}

my $length = 0;

open( UH, "< $upfile" ) or warn "$!\n";
$length += -s $upfile;
my $boundary = 'nn7h23ffh47v98';

my @head = (
    "POST $url HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: $host",
    "User-Agent: z-uploader",
    "Content-Length: $length",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary",
    "",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hostname\"",
    "",
    "$hostname",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ren\"",
    "",
    "true",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: file; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"$upfile\"",
    "--$boundary--",
    "",
    "",
);

my $header = join( "\r\n", @head );
$length += length($header);
$head[3] = "Content-Length: $length";
$header = join( "\r\n", @head );
$length = -s $upfile;
$length += length($header);

select SOCK;
$| = 1;

print SOCK $header;

while ( sysread( UH, my $buf, 8196 ) ) {
    if ( length($buf) < 8196 ) {
        $buf = $buf . "\r\n--$boundary";
        syswrite SOCK, $buf, length($buf);
    } else {
        syswrite SOCK, $buf, 8196;
    }
    print STDOUT '.',;
}

close UH;

shutdown SOCK, 1;

my @data = (<SOCK>);
print STDOUT "result->@data\n";
close SOCK;
```

Anybody see something that jumps out at them?

**UPDATE:**

I made the following updates, and the errors appear to be unchanged.

To address the content-length issue, and attempt to eliminate the potential for the loop equalling the exact number of characters before appending the final boundary, I made the following code update.

```
my $boundary = 'nn7h23ffh47v98';
my $content = <<EOF;
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hostname"

$hostname
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: file; name="filename"; filename="$upfile"
--$boundary--


EOF

$length += length($content);
my $header = <<EOF;
POST $url HTTP/1.1
Host: $host
User-Agent: z-uploader
Content-Length: $length
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary

EOF

$header .= $content;
select SOCK;
$| = 1;

print SOCK $header;

my $incr = ($length + 100) / 20;
$incr = sprintf("%.0f", $incr);

while (sysread(UH, my $buf, $incr )) {
syswrite SOCK, $buf, $incr;
}
syswrite SOCK, "\n--$boundary", $incr;
```

Comment: 99% of your code and the million issues therein can be eliminated by using `use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST ); use LWP::UserAgent qw( ); my $response = LWP::UserAgent->new->post('http://url.mycompany.com/csmtar.cgi', Content_Type => 'form-data', Content => [ filename => [ $file_name ], hostname => $host_name, ren => 'true' ])->as_string());`

Comment: Agreed, but as I said, such modules are not available on the Unix servers in our environment, and it's not realistic to install them on hundreds of servers for this solitary purpose.

Comment: Well that's obviously not true, seeing as you plan on doing just that with the script you're writing.

Comment: I'm not catching something. What kind of installs am I attempting with this script?

Comment: I'm confused at your confusion. You said putting the module on hundreds of machines was unrealistic, but the only reason you'd need the modules on hundreds of machines is if you placed your script on hundreds of machines. So the only reason it would be unrealistic is if you're already doing it, which is a contradictino.

Comment: so using `scp` or `sftp` is out question? `s`=secure ;-) The the cmd is `scp localFile remuser@remHost:/path/to/remote/dir`.  Good luck!

Comment: scp was the first choice, but facilitating file uploads in an automated fashion from thousands of machines was bringing the server to its knees. On the other hand, HTTP is made for things like this, and the server weathers HTTP uploads like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if there's "something that jumps out", from looking at the code.

Two things jump out at me:

1) The Content-Length parameter in a POST HTTP message specifies the exact byte count of the entity portion of the HTTP message. See section 4.4 of [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

You are setting the Content-Length: header to the exact size of the of the file you're uploading. Unfortunately, in addition to the file itself, you are also sending the MIME headers.

The "entity" portion of the HTTP message, as defined by RFC 2616, essentially consists of everything after the blank line following the last header of the HTTP message header. *Everything* below that point must be included in the `Content-Length:` header. The `Content-Length` header is NOT the size of the file you're uploading, but the same of the HTTP message's entire entity portion, which follows the header.

2) Ignoring the broken `Content-Length:` header, if the size of the file happens to be an exact multiple of 8196 bytes, the MIME document you are constructing will most likely be corrupted. Your last sysread() call will get the last 8196 bytes in the file, which you will happy copy through, the next call to sysread() will return 0, and you will terminate the loop, without emitting the trailing boundary delimiter. The MIME document will be corrupt.

Comment: Excellent information. I updated the script to only calculate the length of the file to upload, along with the entity, which I've split out into its own scalar to make it easier, instead of the futzing with making the block of text into a list. Thank you very much.